# regex: find all asterisks without prepended backslashes

Tags: python, regex

I am building a regex that transforms `*asterisks*` into `<b>bold tags</b>`, as a simpler version of Markdown. The regex looks like this:

```
markdown = '\*(?P<name>.+)\*'
bold = '<b>\g<name></b>'
text = 'abcdef *bold* ghijkl'
print(re.sub(markdown, bold, text))

>>> abcdef <b>bold</b> ghijkl
```

Now I need to ignore escaped asterisks `\*`, and here I run into two problems:

### Problem 1

When I try to specify escape symbol as `\\`

```
markdown = '[^\\]\*(?P<name>.+)[^\\]\*'
```

I get a Python error:

```
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

so there is a syntax error somewhere, can't seem to fix it.

### Problem 2

Suppose I want to ignore prepended symbol `A` (not a backslash). Here my regex works:

```
markdown = '[^A]\*(?P<name>.+)[^A]\*'
bold = '<b>\g<name></b>'
text = 'abcdef A*bold* ghijkl'
print(re.sub(markdown, bold, text))

>>> abcdef A*bold* ghijkl
```

But if there are no prepending `A`'s in my line, some valuable symbols from the text are consumed by the regex:

```
text = 'abcdef *bold* ghijkl'
print(re.sub(markdown, bold, text))

>>> abcdef<b>bol</b> ghijkl
```

Note the first space  and letter `d` have disappeared.

How do I deal with these two problems?

Comment: A regex won't work in all scenarios, write a simple parser.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1a: Syntax Error**

It's not working, because you have to escape the backslashes as well.

```
markdown = '[^\\\\]\*(?P<name>.+)[^\\\\]\*'
```

Or use `r''` to define a raw string.

```
markdown = r'[^\\]\*(?P<name>.+)[^\\]\*'
```

**Problem 1b: Solution**

My advice: Don't try to solve it with one regex.

1. Custom escape the problematic character.
2. Run the normal regex.
3. Undo the custom escape.

Code:

```
my_escapes = {
    '%backslash-escaped%': '\\\\',
    '%bold-escaped%': '\\*',
}

text = r'text \*not-bold text2 *bold* text3 \\*bold* text4 \\\*not-bold text5 \\\\*bold* text6'
text = re.sub('\\\\\\\\', '%backslash-escaped%', text)  # escape escaped escape characters
text = re.sub('\\\\\*', '%bold-escaped%', text)  # escape escaped bold characters
text = re.sub('(?<!\\\\)\*(?P<bold>[^\*\\\\]+)\*', '<b>\g<bold></b>', text)  # add bold parts

# undo all escapes
for key, value in my_escapes.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(key, value)

print text

>>> text \*not-bold text2 <b>bold</b> text3 \\<b>bold</b> text4 \\\*not-bold text5 \\\\<b>bold</b> text6
```

**Problem 2: Disappearing of characters**

They disappear, because you have matched but not re-inserted them. To do so, wrap them in groups (here named groups) and
insert the groups inside the replacement-string.

```
markdown = '(?P<first_char>[^A])\*(?P<name>.+)(?P<sec_char>[^A])\*'
bold = '\g<first_char><b>\g<name></b>\g<sec_char>'
```

Or use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), they will match but not consume the character.

```
markdown = '(?<!A)\*(?P<name>.+)(?!A)\*'
bold = '<b>\g<name></b>'
```